# How Can I use Query in Azure Scheduler?

Tags: azure, scheduler

I couldn't find a method about using Query in Azure Scheduler.

Please Let me know If you know this.

Thank you.

Comment: When I googled "Query in Azure Scheduler" I got a lot of results. how about you?

Answer (score 2):

Azure scheduler lets you create jobs in the cloud that reliably invoke services inside and outside of Azure—such as calling HTTP/S endpoints or posting messages to Azure Storage queues. In your scenarios, you can code your Query logic in your endpoint. And call the endpoint using the Azure scheduler job.